# Apache NiFi - Data Web Service

Tags: web-services, dataflow, apache-nifi

I'm trying to create a web service dataflow using Apache NiFi. I've setup the request and response http processors however I can't seem to figure out how to update the flowfile from the request processor with data from say... another connection. Can someone please let me know how I can achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 4):

You would need a processor that can take an incoming flow file and replace the contents with results. One example would be the ExecuteSQL processor which will replace the contents of an incoming flow file with the results of querying the database (in Avro format). So a flow of HandleHttpRequest -> ExecuteSQL -> HandleHttpResponse.

One problem is that many processors that retrieve data from somewhere are not meant to take incoming flow files. For example, processors like GetSolr, GetHBase, and many other Get processors are meant to be source processors on their own.

Comment: Hi Bryan. Yes the fact that some processors are not meant to take incoming connections is my issue. I need to build a custom processor that will sit in between the HandleHttpRequest and HandleHttpResponse processors. This custom processor will able to able to accept a second incoming connection and its flowfiles will be used to replace the contents of the flowfile in the first connection. Sort of a connection 'lookup' processor. I will attempt this and make it available on github.